# I simply dont Understand how more specific can one be?

Tags: discussion

In this Question [how-to-get-the-form-id-in-drupal-8-with-hook-form-alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202311/how-to-get-the-form-id-in-drupal-8-with-hook-form-alter/202313#202313) all she asked was while placing the hook in a .module file the **dpm** for **fetching $form_id**(**obvious from the code**) is not getting displayed .

> so what shall she do to achieve this ?

I see the question being explained well and also with proper coding 
but suddenly I see 
[image]

> I would like to know how much more does one need to be specific ??

giving details would be helpful ..

**Thankyou**

Comment: The question is how to get the form ID using `hook_form_alter()` which gets it as parameter. The OP didn't say what exactly it should be added. We cannot explain that `dpm()` should be avoided in those cases, that the form ID is passed as parameter, that she probably forgot to add a `use` line, and something else. The question seems to require users to guess what she did wrong, since she didn't ask any explicit, not vague, questions.

Comment: In fact, the given answers all say _try this_, which seems to mean _I don't know if this is exactly your problem; I am just guessing._ She could have put the `use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;` at the beginning of that file, as it is done from Drupal core; we cannot know this, since she didn't see all the code, so we are just guessing what she means and what the problem could be.

Comment: Thankyou for showing me the coding standard :) Yes, i agree we should use the use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface; 
Also I think  both title and content explain itself what did she want to achieve .. YES  if the title did contradict with the body then there might arise a confusion among readers but both the title and the content is itself self-explanatory what was her ultimate objective.@kiamlaluno

Comment: Exactly: the title and the content are a contradiction. It doesn't seem so self-explanatory, though, if two users had to say _try this_.